# How to inject (in a source) multiple agents but with different parameter settings

Tags: anylogic

I am currently building a model on a manufacture process line and I am trying to inject multiple agents in the model in a specific moment. The agents are components and there are different types of it (blades and tower). What I want to implement is for example injecting 6 new agents in the source and then specify that 2 of them are  component.type='blade' and 4 of them are
component.type='tower'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through `Enter` block. You can't join it to a Source block (because it acts like a Source block), but for the next block in the sequence. Create programmatically new agents, then send them to the `Enter` block.

```
Component component = new Component (param1, param2,...);
component.type = 'blade'
enterComponent.take(component);
```